# Having regex_matches exclude cases where both capturing groups match a 0-length string

Tags: postgresql, array, postgresql-11, regular-expression

I'll trying to write a regex pattern that will help me create an array of length 2 arrays such that each inner array is matched like so:
I'm looking to split sequences that begin with a positive or negative integer followed by a sequence of letters and periods that begins with a letter.  Neither the integer nor sequence of letters/periods is required, but at least one should be for it to match.

I don't know that that's a very clear description, so here's an example.  The string `'9a.-16.y -y. -7hello world'` should return `{{9, a.},{-16,},{,y},{,y.},{-7,hello},{,world}}`.

I've gotten pretty close with the following code

```sql
select array(
  select regexp_matches(
    '9a.-16.y -y. -7hello world',
    '(-\d+|\d*)([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z.]*|)',
    'g'
));
```

But it's including cases where neither capturing group matches.

```
{{9,a.},{-16,},{,},{,y},{,},{,},{,y.},{,},{-7,hello},{,},{,world},{,}}
```

Comment: What does the final pipe mean? Nrmally it's OR,  but it appears to be followed by nothing - which is meaningless? What happens if you take it out?

Comment: The empty strings turn into null's.

Comment: An OR pipe between the two matches, plus another for the case of having both of them? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13351990/in-a-regular-expression-match-one-thing-or-another-or-both)

Answer (score 1):

I can get this by making the whole preface digit optional and ignoring the trailing pipe you put in the last group, I think you can remove the NULLs after by another process:

```
select array(
  select regexp_matches(
    '9a.-16.y -y. -7hello world',
    '(-\d+|\d+)?([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z.]*)',
    'g'
));
                        array                        
-----------------------------------------------------
 {{9,a.},{NULL,y},{NULL,y.},{-7,hello},{NULL,world}}
```